# Count how often words from a list appear in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, nlp

I have a pre-defined list of words; e.g.:

```
wordlist = [["one"],["two"],["three"]]
```

And I have a large corpus of .txt files, also imported into python as a list, e.g.:

```
corpus = ["my friend has one potato",
"i have two bananas and three apples",
"my dad has three apples"]
```

I want a formula that goes through the corpus line by line and tells me the amount of words from my wordlist that are contained in each line; i.e., exemplary output would be:

```
1
2
1
```

I need no differentiation between the words in the wordlist.

However, I want this to be a formula, so that I can easily apply it with different word lists or corpora.

I have not found an answer on SO or elsewhere. What I have tried is:

```
wordcount_total=list()
for i in range(len(corpus)):
    row=corpus[i]
    wordcount_row=sum(1 for word in row.split() if word in wordlist)
    wordcount_total.append(wordcount_row)
```

However, this gives me:

```
0
0
0
```

Many thanks to anyone willing to help!

Comment: Why is your word list nested? I don't think `in` does a deep search; it's only a shallow, top level membership test.

Comment: You should store your `wordlist` in a set because it allows you to check if something is in the set very quickly. Also you have your `wordlist` as a list of lists instead of a list of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
sum(1 for word in row.split() if word in wordlist)
```

`word` is a string, but `wordlist` is a list of *list of strings*. The two aren't comparable.

You can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to flatten your nested list. You can also simplify your logic by calculating the lengths of `set` intersections:

```
from itertools import chain

word_set = set(chain.from_iterable(wordlist))
res = [len(word_set & set(line.split())) for line in corpus]

[1, 2, 1]
```

Comment: One follow-up: By calculating set intersections, your formula above does not count multiple instances of the same word (from the list) in the text. It works in the example above, but if a sentence in the corpus were "I have one apple and one banana", your formula would return "1" for that sentence. So I needed to combine your hint regarding the word set with my original formula.

Comment: @Adam, That's a bit more involved. You probably want to use `Counter(x.split())` and feed to `sum` via a generator expression and an `if` statement. Give it a go, if you're stuck you can ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Create a helper function like so:

```
def find_num_occurences(word, string):
    return string.lower().split().count(word)
```

Then, use this on each word in your string of words you're looking for:

```
for word in wordlist:
    word_count = 0
    for line in corpus:
        sum_in_line = find_num_occurences(word, line)
        word_count = word_count + sum_in_line
    print(word_count)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, though I found the answer by jpp above to be more efficient. This was very easy to understand though.

Comment: @Adam Admittedly, yeah jpp has a better answer. Glad you found mine easier to understand though : )

Answer (score 1):

Consider also using `collections.Counter` for this.

```
counts = collections.Counter()
for line in corpus:
    for word in line.split():
        if word in wordlist:
            counts[word] += 1
```

Assuming you're using `sklearn` already in and around whatever NLP you're doing, another option is to use `sklearn`'s `CountVectorizer` for this and then just go in after the fact to look at the vocabulary to see the counts:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
vectorizer.fit(corpus)
vectorizer.vocabulary_
```

... where `.vocabulary_` will be a dict-like object that has counts per word.

This latter method will scale nicely to other NLP-isms too (e.g. stopword removal, tf-idf weighting).